# How to plot particular line chart with labels and titles in power point using python-pptx module?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx, line-plot

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
A       B       C       D
AR    20201     1     200
AR    20202     1     300
AR    20203     1     1000
AR    20204     1     3000
AR    20205     1     700
AR    20206     1     800
AR    20207     1     900

AR    20201     2    1000
AR    20202     2    2000
AR    20203     2    3000
AR    20204     2    4000
AR    20205     2    5676
AR    20206     2    6000
AR    20207     2    1000

AR    20201     3   4500
AR    20202     3   4567
AR    20203     3   1000
AR    20204     3   900
AR    20205     3   600
AR    20206     3   200
AR    20207     3  100

==========================
BR    20201     1
BR    20202     1
BR    20203     1
BR    20204     1
BR    20205     1
BR    20206     1
BR    20207     1

BR    20201     2
BR    20202     2
BR    20203     2
BR    20204     2
BR    20205     2
BR    20206     2
BR    20207     2

BR    20201     3
BR    20202     3
BR    20203     3
BR    20204     3
BR    20205     3
BR    20206     3
BR    20207     3
```

I am using loop to create multile line charts in ppt. For `country ( Column A)=AR` I am plotting line charts for different `C=1,2 and 3` on same plot. In the `Y axis` I will have `column D` and on `X axis` I will have `column B`

Similary for different country.

I am not able to choose particular line graph available in ppt which also shows `Y-DATA LABELS`. Also my X-axis is not properly formatted. How to align x labels 45 degree slanting.

Here is the code for one country:

```
chart_data = ChartData()
cat=['202001','202002','202003','202004','202005','202006','202007']
chart_data.categories = cat
        
for i in list(data["C"].unique()):
            
    chart_data.add_series(i,tuple(data[data['C']==i]['D']))
    x, y, cx, cy = Inches(1), Inches(1), Inches(10.5), Inches(6)
    chart = slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.LINE, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data).chart

    chart.has_legend = True
    chart.legend.include_in_layout = False
    chart.series[0].smooth = True
```

Output is not of above data:
[image]

The x-axis is not properly spaced and also Y-labels is not there. What I am looking is his line plot which I picked from ppt ( `Line with markers and annotations`):

[image]

How can I change the above code to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `chart.series[0].data_labels` here?: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/chart.html#pptx.chart.series.LineSeries

Comment: ok. How to align the x axis labels? Any help.

Comment: can you change the above code so that I can understand better?

Comment: How to add a verical dotted line at 202004?